# Add copied text to a lineEdit when a button is pushed

Tags: c++, qt

I just started reading into QT but I don't quite get the SIGNAL SLOT functions.
I have a form with 2 QLineEdit and I want to copy the text from the first QLineEdit to the second one when a button is clicked but I don't know how to set up the connect function properly.

I tried tying textChanged function to itself but the result is that the text will edit everytime I press a letter, since that's the signal.

```
newForm::newForm() {
    widget.setupUi(this);
    connect(widget.nameEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString&)),
            this, SLOT(textChanged(const QString&)));
    connect(widget.pushMe, SIGNAL(pressed()),
            this, SLOT(handleButton()));
}
void newForm::handleButton(){
}
```

I think I have to do something inside the handleButton function but I don't understand how to read and copy the text from the first line since the text() doesn't work inside handleButton

Comment: One way is to access the widget directly. A second way is to have a QString variable in your newForm class that gets set in the `textChanged()` member function.

Answer (score 0):

To copy the text from the first `QLineEdit` called `widget.nameEdit` to a second one, `widget.nameEdit2`, when a button is clicked, you can do it with one SIGNAL/SLOT connection using the `QLineEdit` `setText()` in a `lambda`:

```
connect(widget.pushMe, &QPushButton::released,this, [=](){  
widget.nameEdit2.setText(widget.nameEdit.text());
};
```

You don't need to use the first `QLineEdit` `textChanged()` signal, and the above connection copies the whole text available in first field to second filed all at once when you press the button. One the other hand, if you want second `QLineEdit` to get updated continuously as text changes in first field, then you could use the `textchanged()` signal of first field , to `setText()` of second :

```
connect(widget.nameEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged,
            widget.nameEdit2, &QLineEdit::setText);
```